Float point error, threshold when using deSolve and functions
I'm trying to construct a simple viral dynamics model for which I wrote a function modelling ODEs for three different rates. For some reason, despite a negative term in one of the ODEs, when I solve it using the ode function from the deSolve package, it never actually reaches 0 which messes up the model since it's super sensitive to any perturbations.
When the value reaches a certain value I want the function to substitute it for a 0 and then continue. I know that there's some if statement I need to put somewhere but I've tried everything and it's not working and the model remains unchanged every time I run the simulation.
Here is the function in case it helps:
pars <- c(lambda = 0.272,      # production of uninfected cells per day
          beta = 0.00027,  # rate of infection by virus per day
          dt = 0.00136, # rate of death of uninfected cells per day
          di = 0.33, # rate of death of infected cells per day
          k = 100, # rate of production of free virus per day
          c = 2, # rate of natural virus death rate per day
          beta_treatment = 0,
          drug_start = 50, 
          drug_end = 365)

times <- seq(0, 3650, 1)

startC <- c(t0 = 1000, i0 = 0, v0 = 500) # t = target cell, i = infected cell, v = virus

ViralDynamics <- function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    if (t >= drug_start & t <= drug_end) {
      dtdt <- lambda - beta_treatment*t0*v0 - dt*t0 # rate of t cell production per day 
      didt <- beta_treatment*t0*v0 - di*i0 # rate of conversion of t cell to infected t cell
      dvdt <- k*i0 - c*v0 # rate of viral production per day 
      if (i0 < 0.001) {
        i0 <- 0
      }
      return(list(c(dtdt, didt, dvdt)))
    } else {
      dtdt <- lambda - beta*t0*v0 - dt*t0 # rate of t cell production per day 
      didt <- beta*t0*v0 - di*i0 # rate of conversion of t cell to infected t cell
      dvdt <- k*i0 - c*v0 # rate of viral production per day 
      if (i0 < 0.001) {
        i0 <- 0
      }
      return(list(c(dtdt, didt, dvdt)))
    }
  })
}

solution <- ode(y = startC, times = times, func = ViralDynamics, parms = pars,
                method = "ode45")


Could you show the complete code with your attempted "if" statement? And please supply all data needed to run your function.

I've updated the complete code with all of the parameters

An if-statement within an ODE model is rarely a good idea and should be avoided. The correct way to implement this is to use forcings or events, see the help pages of the deSolve package. You can also find some related examples on Stackoverflow and for example here.

I think the main reason was that setting i0 to zero occured at the end of the model function. An ode model function returns only derivatives to the solver, so this is just ignored, because the solver takes care of the states. This is how it usually works, the details would be a separate topic.
Setting a state variable arbitrarily to a fixed value can be done by an event function or an event function triggered by a root function. This is described in the deSolve help pages and a small tutorial.
It needs a little bit more overhead, so I think for the problem here, we might implement it pragmatically with if-statements, knowing that such discontinuities in differential equation models are not ideal.
ViralDynamics <- function(t, state, parameters){
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
  
    if (t>= drug_start & t<= drug_end) beta <- beta_treatment
    if (i0 < 0.001) i0 <- 0
  
    dtdt <-  lambda - beta * t0 * v0 - dt*t0 
    didt <- beta * t0 * v0 - di*i0
    dvdt <- k*i0 - c*v0 
    return(list(c(dtdt, didt, dvdt), beta=beta))
  })
}

solution <- ode(y = startC, times = times, func = ViralDynamics, parms = pars, method = "lsoda")

plot(solution)

Some more suggestions:

Instead of using an if for two versions of the whole ODE system, it is more compact and less error prone to use a generalized formulation and change only the parameter beta.
The ode45 solver works, but the default lsoda is better, i.e. more robust and faster.
It is possible to add additional "auxilliary" values to the returned list for debugging and plotting, e.g. beta.


Edit:
Originally, I wondered about the very dramatic changes at the beginning of the simulation, because such behaviour may indicate unrealistic parameters or initial values. However, the original poster confirmed this as a typical behaviour and as we know, viruses are fast.

Actually, the behavior observed in the first few days of infection is not unrealistic at all. In the case of HIV (which is what I'm modelling here with accurate parameter values), there is a huge peak of viral load but that depletes just as fast since there's more infection, there's less uninfected cells to infect by the virus. Thank you so much for the comprehensive reply!

I see. I know that viruses are fast, so just said, may indicate  ... In that case, one could make the output time steps a little bit narrower in the first part of the simulation and wider in the second. This has (almost) no influence on precision, because the internal time step is calculated automatically anyway.
